# How do I replace AND (&&) in a for loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, for

I'd like to find an equivalent of

```
cmd 1 && cmd 2 && ... && cmd 20
```

but with commands expressed within a `for` loop like

```
for i in {1..20}
do
   cmd $i
done
```

What would you suggest to change in the second expression to find an equivalent of the first?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The equivalent to your original sequence would be:

```
for i in {1..20}
do
   cmd $i || break
done
```

The difference with Amit's answer is the script won't exit, i.e. will execute potential commands that might follow the sequence/loop. Note that the return status of the whole loop will always be true with my suggestion, this might be fixed if relevant in your case.

Comment: Agreed, this more closely follows the behaviour of `cmd && cmd`

Answer (score 9):

If you want a dirty one-line solution, you can create a command and send it to bash.

```
echo "cmd "{1..20}" &&" : | bash
```

Comment: we should create an IObashCC ^^

Answer (score 8):

You can break out of the loop if one of them failed

```
for i in {1..55}; do
    if ! cmd $i; then
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: like @jiliagre noted (and provided a correction in his answer), this does not "break out of the loop", it exits the calling shell.

Comment: Isn't `break` legal there? I'm pretty sure the `if` statement doesn't interfere..

Answer (score 0):

This is how i execute my tasks in terminal without using `&&`

```
 for i in google.com yahoo.com;do ping -c1 $i;echo $i;done
```

Similar to you have to put this command in a script

```
 for i in google.com yahoo.com
    do echo $i;ping -c1 $i;
  done
```

Both giving same output to me

> google.com PING google.com (172.217.26.174) 56(84) bytes of data. 64
>   bytes from google.com (172.217.26.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=259 ms
>
> --- google.com ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
>   259.794/259.794/259.794/0.000 ms yahoo.com PING yahoo.com (98.138.253.109) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from yahoo.com
>   (98.138.253.109): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=398 ms
>
> --- yahoo.com ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
>   398.974/398.974/398.974/0.000 ms